# Why can't I set the system clock on my Dell Latitude C510?

Tags: laptop, bios, clock, dell-latitude

Whenever I open Chromium and visit any website, Chromium thinks that the certificate isn't valid yet. I know that's because of the system clock, and when I try to change the system clock nothing happens. The BIOS also gives me a warning on boot saying the system clock has not been set and setting it also does nothing. I would like to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likley need to replace the CMOS battery.The [C510 service manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latc610/en/index.htm) can be downloaded.  Battery is likley fairly inexpensive so worth trying.

Comment: Some of my friends recommended re-installing my BIOS. Would this do anything?

Comment: @user1610406 Re-installing the BIOS has nothing to do with the system clock. As Dave said, it sounds like your CMOS battery needs to be replaced. The battery powers the CMOS RAM that stores BIOS setting and runs the real-time clock on the computer when the power is tuned off.